# Imputing binary missing data with hmi and mice -- Error: C stack usage 7969776 is too close to the limit

Tags: multilevel-analysis, missing-data, binary-data

I'm running HMI on two level data (students in courses) with missing data at the student level. The code throws the following error (Error: C stack usage  7969776 is too close to the limit) when I include a binary value (gender) with missing data.

Below is a reproducible example.

```
library(MCMCglmm)
library(hmi)
library(mice)

df <- data.frame(post = rtnorm(100,60,20,0,100),
                 pre = rtnorm(100,40,20,0,100),
                 gender = rbinom(n=100, size=1, prob=0.20),
                 course = rep( c("A","B","C","D"), 100*c(0.1,0.2,0.65,0.05) ))
df$post[1:round((0.3)*length(df$post),digits = 0)] <- NA
df$gender[round((0.2)*length(df$post),digits = 0):round((0.5)*length(df$post),
                                                            digits = 0)] <- NA

hmi_test <- hmi(df, model_formula = post ~ 1 + pre + gender + (1|course ), 
                M = 2, maxit = 5, list_of_types = NULL, nitt = 3000,  burnin = 1000)

list_of_types_maker(df)
```

Comment: Hey Jayson, welcome to the site - I think you might want to migrate this question over to stackoverflow (an associated site) as they focus more on programming matters and you are more likely to get the help you are after. CrossValidated is a forum to help with statistics.

Comment: I suspect you need `m = 2` rather than `M = 2` and I am getting the error message `Error in if (tmp_type == "roundedcont") { : argument is of length zero`

Comment: The M isn't the source. It runs fine if there is no missing data in the binary variable or if the binary variable is excluded from the analysis.